# Service loader with constructors

Tags: java, oop

So, here's the structure I have

```
interface FactoryService {
    Foo createFoo(int a, String b);
}

@AutoService(FactoryService.class)
class SomeFactory implements FactoryService {
    public Foo createFoo(int a, String b) {
        // How to implement service loader here, which loads Foo
    }
}

interface Foo {
    void opsForFoo(InputStream s, OutputStream o)
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
    // Constructor
    public FooImpl(int a, String b) {}
    public void opsForFoo(InputStream s, OutputStream o) {
        // perform operation here
    }
}
```

How can I implement ServiceLoader in `SomeFactory` class? The issue I have is `FooImpl` takes in two values from the constructor. I could just do `new FooImpl(a, b)`, but is it correct? Going forward there can be other classes that implement `Foo`

Answer (score 1):

The point of the serviceloader infrastructure is that you can define any number of classes that are implementations of whatever you're making a serviceloader for, and they can be anywhere in the classpath.

For example, in your example, you are going to serviceload 'FactoryService' (not foo!), so, your code can provide any number of implementations of FactoryService, and whatever is doing the service loading will get 1 instance of each and every such FactoryService class you've set up. Here, you're setting up one such class, called 'SomeFactory'.

THIS particular FactoryService variant (your 'SomeFactory') will, upon being invoked (upon its `createFoo` method being called), return an instance of FooImpl.

If, some day, there is a different impl of Foo, you have 2 options:

[1] expand your SomeFactory class to return this different impl depending on whatever you want (it's code, after all, sky's the limit). For example: `return a < 0 ? new NegativeFooImpl(Math.abs(a), b) : new PositiveFooImpl(a, b);`

[2] make a second class that also implements FactoryService.

The general layout of the `FactoryService` here is a tad odd: Given that there are, say, 10 factoryservices, what's the idea here? Some request comes in, whatever is doing the serviceloading for factoryservice calls all 10 services, producing 10 foos, and then.. picks one? Presumably the `FactoryService` interface needs some javadoc with, say: `/** If a and b are such that this call is not for you, return null. The code that loads foos will go with the Foo value returned by the first implementation of FactoryService called that returns non-null. */`

For example, that last one would look a bit like:

```
public class FooMaker {
    ServiceLoader<FactoryService> fooFactories = ServiceLoader.load(FactoryService.class);

    public Foo createAFoo(int a, String b) {
        for (FactoryService factory : fooFactories) {
            Foo foo = factory.createFoo(a, b);
            if (foo != null) return foo;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, considering there's no `FooImpl` in this scenario. How can I create an implementation of Foo such that I can pass in those two data (`a, b`) ?

Comment: If I don’t use that to create Foo, then what’s the other way?